# Where i can find latest compiled Animation nodes for windows 7 32 bit?

Tags: animation-nodes

I tried my best to compile Animation nodes for my OS (windows 7 32-bit) but as i am not from programming backgroud and neither i am a techie guy, I found it quiet hard to compile.
Is there is anyone who has compiled AN for the same OS i have? If yes, then please upload that to github or other link for me.
I am stuck with version 1.6 of animation nodes.

Comment: I managed to compile AN2 for Windows 7 32bit. Don't know if this was really necessary or not, but in addition to VS Build Tools I installed the Python with Blender's Python version, pip installed CPython and that seemed to work. Will provide the compilation result later.

Comment: Ok buddy, waiting for you.

Comment: [Here you go](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nndi971odvceus4/animation_nodes_2_for_win_7_32bit.zip?dl=0) – with latest `master` and `v2.1` versions. I added some text of how I think I got the whole things to compile, but that was long ago, so I don't know if this is the way to go. HTH

Comment: I tried to understand that redme.md file and learnt a lot via surfing the internet. Thanks a lot. Now i really respect the developers. But my problem is not solved yet. Version 1.6 works but when i replace that folder with the versions you have given, then it show error message. Maybe i have to use blender to earn some money and buy a new laptop. Btw, thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you will end up being “techie guy” after all :) Did you also (successfully?) try to install one of the builds or are you on to building it yourself then?

Answer (score 4):

There are no 32-bit builds for Animation Nodes. The developer said in this [issue](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/793):

> So far I never compiled AN for a 32 bit system. It should be possible somehow but I don't know how without having access to a 32 bit system myself.

And the [release page](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases) states that for the 2.1 test builds:

> Also 32 bit operating systems are not supported.

And for version 2.0:

> Only 64 bit systems are supported for now.

Answer (score -1):

32-bit is obsolete for new computers, as someone told me. 64-bit is in, as too 96-bit. Anyway, most CG softwares today require 64-bit (minimum), as stated in specs. Time for new computer. It will be cheaper to buy new computer than upgrade your old.

Comment: What is "94-bit"? 32-bit *can* be installed on new hardware, it's just that it won't be able to use all resources available for that hardware

Comment: @Mr Zak, I just re-edited my answer. I made the mistake with 94-bit instead of 96-bit. Sorry for confusion. I meant 96-bit as it is so in Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050. New Intel Core i9 too is 96-bit.

Comment: 32-bit computers are becoming increasingly obsolete. https://youtu.be/xoVNG9IVknw